# Main axis are not shown when using grid

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, axis, grid-layout

I want to plot two graphs into the same figure with two different y-axis. In addition to it, I would like to add a grid and then save the plot as pdf.

**My problem** is that - while the grid is drawn correctly - the main axis are not shown anymore. How can they be plotted as well? I am using `matplotlib 1.5.1` and `Python 2.7.11`.

Here is the plot:

[image]

And here is the code I am using:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

pp = PdfPages('myplot.pdf')

x = np.linspace(0.1, 10, 100)
y1 = np.exp(x)
y2 = np.log(x)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.plot(x, y1, '-ro', markersize=5, label='y1')
ax1.set_ylim(-0.1, 1.1 * max(y1))
ax1.set_ylabel('y1', fontsize=20)
ax1.legend(loc='upper left')
ax1.grid(ls='dotted', c='k')
ax1.patch.set_facecolor('white')

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.grid(False)
ax2.plot(x, y2, 'b-', label='y2')
ax2.set_ylim(-0.1, 1.1 * max(y2))
ax2.set_ylabel('y2', fontsize=20)
ax2.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.xlim([-0.5, 1.05 * max(x)])
ax1.set_xlabel('x', fontsize=20)

pp.savefig(fig)
pp.close()
plt.close(fig)
```

Comment: It works for me... (Python 3.4.4 mac OS) but throws a `RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log`

Comment: @ReblochonMasque: Are you using the exact same code? The plot you get looks different from mine? The RunTimeWarning appears because `log(0)` is calculated (I changed that).

Comment: Yes, it shows the axis and a frame around the canvas. I'll post a png in a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me with the plot correctly showing the axis like on the png added here under.

Same output for the following:

- `Python 3.4.4, iPython, Jupyter notebook, matplotlib 1.5.1`
- `Python 2.7.11, iPython, Jupyter notebook, matplotlib 1.5.?`

[image]

The code used is this one - same as the one posted except for the plt.show() that I added to produce the png image.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

pp = PdfPages('myplot.pdf')

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 100)
y1 = np.exp(x)
y2 = np.log(x)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.plot(x, y1, '-ro', markersize=5, label='y1')
ax1.set_ylim(-0.1, 1.1 * max(y1))
ax1.set_ylabel('y1', fontsize=20)
ax1.legend(loc='upper left')
ax1.grid(ls='dotted', c='k')
ax1.patch.set_facecolor('white')

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.grid(False)
ax2.plot(x, y2, 'b-', label='y2')
ax2.set_ylim(-0.1, 1.1 * max(y2))
ax2.set_ylabel('y2', fontsize=20)
ax2.legend(loc='upper right')
plt.xlim([-0.5, 1.05 * max(x)])
ax1.set_xlabel('x', fontsize=20)

#plt.show()

pp.savefig(fig)
pp.close()
plt.close(fig)
```

If you are using an ipython kernel, there might be some residual settings from previous work interfering with the rendering? Have you tried with a fresh kernel?

Comment: That would be the expected output. Which version of matplotlib are you using (I use 1.5.1)? Any chance you could try it on Python 2.7.?

Comment: Yes, matplotlib 1.5.1 on python 3.4.4 on mac os. I get the exact same result with python 2.7.11 on mac os (you are lucky I had both kernels running concurrently ;)). kernel ran from jupyter notebook in both cases.

Comment: Ok, running it from the command line, indeed results in the correct plot. Now I still have to figure out why it works for the above toy example but not for the actual plot (where it still fails)... Thanks for your help - I upvote it for now and accept it later...

Comment: Sorry I could not solve it, but it is difficult to do much when unable to reproduce the fault... Glad I could modestly help you though. :) Cheers.

Comment: Oh, you helped a lot already, thanks! Seems I found the issue: In my actual file I also have an `import seaborn` statement which causes the trouble. If I comment it, everything works as intended. I would not have thought about this without your "interfering" comment. That's why the above example worked when I run it from the commen line: there was no `import seaborn`. Before I was running it in the same ipython session where I was running the `seaborn` stuff, too.