# Matplotlib savefig pdf doesn't display some polygons

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm making a relatively simple plot that seemed to work fine. I have a number of line segments, and each defines an area. I'm using polygons for the filled areas using `plot.Polygon` and `ax.add_patch`.

When I save to .png, everything works fine. So, I turn to pdf for the final image.  I manually set things like `fontsize`, `figsize` and `dpi`, so there should be no problem.

Sadly, 2 out of the four `Polygons` in the current picture are not displayed in the pdf. Which is strange; the previous two images (other datasets) did act correctly. I've played around a bit with `zorder` and `alpha` on the `Polygons` but to no avail.

My google search did not turn up anything; it mentioned the `dpi` being different if you haven't set it manually, but this is no problem. Beyond that, I could find no clear reasons.

My sincere thanks,
Daimonie

Comment: There was a somewhat similar question yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36467770/main-axis-are-not-shown-when-using-grid/36468328?noredirect=1#comment60549858_36468328 ; it was some other module interfering with the generation of the pdf. Take a look, and maybe you want to construct a minimal example, then add features one at a time to find out what breaks the output?

Comment: That question doesn't seem that similar (to me), as his problems are different. I doubt another module is interfering - partially because the other images worked, partially because I'm only using ``numpy`` and ``matplotlib``. I'll try to see if I can generate a minimal example.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I've found the problem.

Let's first denote the method I use to add the polygons, just for clarity. The points $(x,y)$ that define the vertices are called `vertices`. The polygon is made as:

```
first_polygon = plt.Polygon(vertices, zorder=.1, facecolor=colours[colour_index], alpha=fill_opacity)
```

Next, I add it to the figure:

```
ax.add_patch(first_polygon)
```

So why didn't it display some polygons? I cannot be sure of the reason, but the issue resolved when I redefined the polygons. The two polygons that didn't display were bound by three lines. The first polygon was bound by `y0, y1, y2` and the 'frame' of the figure. Because I was still scaling the figure, I had put the point that bound it by the 'frame'  as $(100, -100)$. When I changed that to $(min_x, min_y)$ it suddenly displayed properly.

Comment: The next five pictures, using the script that used ``min_x, min_y`` I have had no more problems.